# how to check if my shared hosting has suexec or suphp

Tags: php, apache, suphp, suexec

I need to check if my shared host has suexec or suphp. I found this documentation:
http://www.alain.knaff.lu/howto/PhpSuexec/

At the very end of this document there is a test. When I run the test, it says:

Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons in /home.......... on line 3

Is there any other method to check it? (I have SSH access)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best and simplest way I have found to test it is to have a PHP script executing the "id" command:

put the following in a .php file, and uplaod via ft. then, visit the file location in your browser.

```
<?php
system('id');
?>
```

Comment: what's the expected outcome that tells if it is enabled?

Comment: You should see something similar to: "uid=978(username) gid=971(username) groups=971(username)".

Comment: Since the OP says that system() has been disabled, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because of warning system() has been disabled for security reasons, you should run this PHP function getmyuid() instead of system():

```
<?php
echo "<p>Current User ID: ".getmyuid()."</p>";
echo "<p>Current Script Owner: ".get_current_user()."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: getmyuid() returns the uid for the owner of the script, not the user the server is executing the script as.